# How to pass url params in secure way in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am working on a react application. I have a route like this 
`/dashboard/:name/:id/:role` and if I open this link like this `/dashboard/Ram/32142/Plumber`. So here from URL params, I am getting user details. Is there any secure way to pass params using react-router.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.props.match.params.name`

Comment: I can access using this.props.match.params.name.But here my question how to pass params in secure way like "/dashboard/ewrew/234322/ewoirewr"

Comment: @skyshine Until and unless it is on client-side it is not secure. Anyone can read it. So, we should avoid any such information on client side.

Comment: In web using route params only we identify user related details. Here i am asking secure way like making base64 encoding string